# Multiple Layouts in One Ruby on Rails Site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

I have a website that is already up and running. I would like to add a new page on my Ruby on rails Website and would like to make the page look completely different.

```
Different Layout, Different Theme, Everything.
```

I have created a new scaffold for these pages. but am unsure how to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

For different ways to render different layouts, you can also refer to this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/7-all-about-layouts?view=asciicast)

Yes, you can do this by passing some `params` from controller action and checking in `application.html.erb`

Suppose you have `users_controller` and `home` as controller action as your `root` path

Then in users controller

```
def home
   params.store(:diff_page, true)
end
```

In application.html.erb

In your application `content` is the `id` for main div inside body then

```
#content{:class => (params[:diff_page] ? "back-black" : "back-gradient")}
```

`back-black` and `back-gradient` both are css classes which you can define different style and page, background image anything you want

You can also call different partial too, based on params

```
   - if params[:diff_page]
        = render :partial => 'users/new_page'
   - else
        = render :partial => "layouts/page"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the assets for your theme to make the page look completely different. Rails uses the default `app` layout at `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

However, you can create another layout with your theme and render the view using:

```
render layout: "<your-layout-name>"
```

Answer (score 0):

We do this on one of the sites i help manage:  we have two completely different domains, each of which with its own totally unique look and feel, running off the same rails app.  The second domain is called "cmw" within our project structure, and is set up as follows.

## routes

You can put a condition on routes which looks at the request domain, and only runs that route if the domain matches the condition.  So, we put all the cmw routes at the top of the routes file, all with the same condition.  Then, underneath, the regular site routes.  When we get a request to "cmwdomain.com", it will trigger one of the cmw routes.  Requests to "maindomain.com" will fall through all the cmw routes, because they have the condition, which fails for this domain, and hit one of the routes below which are for the main site.

eg

```
#################### START OF CMW ROUTES:  ALL HAVE A CONDITION ON THEM TO DIFFERENTIATE THEM FROM REGULAR ROUTES ###############
cmw = { :host => CMW_HOST_REGEX }  

map.resources :licenses, :controller => "cmw/licenses", :conditions => cmw
map.resources :users, :controller => "cmw/users", :conditions => cmw

#REGULAR ROUTES  
map.resources :licenses, :controller => "licenses"
map.resources :users, :controller => "users"
```

## controllers

The above system sends all of the cmw requests through to controllers in the app/controllers/cmw folder.  Normally, all controllers would extend ApplicationController.  In our case, we have a CmwController which extends ApplicationController, and is kind of like the CMW-specific version of ApplicationController.  This has its own default layout and various protected methods and helpers which are specific to the cmw site.  Then, all the cmw controllers extend CmwController instead of ApplicationController.

## views

To match the views to controllers, we have a folder `app/views/cmw` where all of the different cmw controllers' corresponding view folders live.

This system is nice and clean.  The second "cmw" site has its own routes, controllers and views, but accesses the same models and database as the main site: two faces of the same app.